# New Kernel from Backports does not boot

Tags: debian, kernel, backports

I tried to install the new Linux kernel 4.6.0 on my Debian machine from backports, but my machine won't boot with the new kernel.

Steps that I took:

1. added BPO to `sources.list`
2. `apt-get install ...` (headers and image)
3. reboot

I see an empty screen with a blinking underscore; that's it.

Comment: Found a solution here:
http://jensd.be/27/linux/install-a-newer-kernel-in-debian-7-5-wheezy-or-centos-6-5

I didn't upgrade the backport dependencies

Comment: If a VM in vmware, I also advise to use open-vm-tools 10 from the backports; please add your own answer, and wait the required time to accept it.